# Proof for (2,0) tensor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}\left(\sqrt{a}A^{ijk}\right)$

Tags: tensors

As the title suggests, I want to prove $\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}\left(\sqrt{a}A^{ijk}\right)$ is a type (2,0) tensor when $a={\rm det}\left(a_{ij}\right)>0$; $a_{ij}$ is a type (0,2) symmetric tensor field; $A^{ijk}$ is a totally skew-symmetric (3,0) tensor field; and $\overline x^j=\overline x^j(x^i)$ is a given transformation. Here're my approaches:

1. I notice that
   $$a={\rm det}\left(a_{ij}\right)={\rm det}\left(\frac{\partial\overline{x}^{h}}{\partial x^{i}}\frac{\partial\overline{x}^{k}}{\partial x^{j}}\overline{a}_{hk}\right)=\overline{J}^{2}\overline{a}$$where$\overline{J}={\rm det}\left(\frac{\partial\overline{x}^{h}}{\partial x^{i}}\right)$
2. Rewirte the given relation for the sake of easy manipulation as
   $$
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{k}}\left(\sqrt{a}A^{ijk}\right)=\frac{1}{2a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{k}}A^{ijk}+\frac{\partial A^{ijk}}{\partial x^{k}}
   $$
3. Then, I changed them on the right-hand-side term-by-term. The first term is
   $$
   \frac{1}{2a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial x^{k}}A^{ijk}=\frac{1}{2\overline{J}^{2}\overline{a}}\frac{\partial\left(\overline{J}^{2}\overline{a}\right)}{\partial x^{k}}\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial \overline{x}^{h}}\frac{\partial x^{k}}{\partial \overline{x}^{m}}\overline{A}^{lhm}\\
   =\frac{1}{2\overline{J}^{2}\overline{a}}\left(2\overline{J}\frac{\partial \overline{J}}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}\overline{a}+\overline{J}^{2}\frac{\partial \overline{a}}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}\right)\frac{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}{\partial x^{k}}\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial\overline{x}^{h}}\frac{\partial x^{k}}{\partial \overline{x}^{m}}\overline{A}^{lhm}\\
   =\left(\frac{1}{\overline{J}}\frac{\partial\overline{J}}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}+\frac{1}{2\overline{a}}\frac{\partial\overline{a}}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}\right)\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial \overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial\overline{x}^{h}}\overline{A}^{lhs}
   $$
4. The second term is
   $$
   \frac{\partial A^{ijk}}{\partial x^{k}}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial \overline{x}^{h}}\frac{\partial x^{k}}{\partial \overline{x}^{m}}\overline{A}^{lhm}\right)\frac{\partial \overline{x}^{s}}{\partial x^{k}}\\
   =\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline{x}^{s}}\left(\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial \overline{x}^{h}}\right)\overline{A}^{lhs}+\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial\overline{x}^{h}}\left(\frac{1}{J}\frac {\partial J}{\partial\overline{x}^{m}}\right)\overline{A}^{lhm}+\frac{\partial x^{i}}{\partial\overline{x}^{l}}\frac{\partial x^{j}}{\partial \overline{x}^{h}}\frac{\partial \overline{A}^{lhs}}{\partial \overline{x}^s}
   $$where $J={\rm det}\left(\frac{\partial x^{h}}{\partial \overline{x}^{i}}\right)$ and thus $\overline{J}J=1$.

Here's my problem/question. At the step 4 on the right-hand-side, I cannot remove the firt term while the second term is canceled by the $\overline J$-related first term of the step 3. The last term of the step 4 is the one we want to see for type (2,0) tensor transformation. Please, teach/point where I went wrong or miss some terms. Thanks in advance.